# Returning Device GUIDs and Bios ID, C++, Linux

Tags: c++, linux, guid, bios

I am trying to write a function to return all the GUIDs of the devices attached to the machine, as well as returning the BIOS Id. How would I achieve this? I can only seem to find ways of doing it on a windows machine, but not a linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not assign a GUID to everything. Hardware is identified by hardware-native means, e.g. USB and PCI devices are identifies by vendor and device ID (and serial number).

You can see what data the kernel offers by browsing `/sys`. I'd also check the source of tools like `lspci` and `lsusb` to get an idea on how one retrieves data programmatically (i.e. without parsing files in `/sys`).

There is, by the way, also a tool called `dmidecode`, that does operate directly on DMI data.

Comment: Is there a way of retrieving that?

Comment: You can see what data the kernel offers by browsing `/sys`. I'd also check the source of tools like `lspci` and `lsusb` to get an idea on how one retrieves data programmatically (i.e. without parsing files in `/sys`)